# TensorFlow Object Detection API: What do the losses mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

What do each of the following losses mean? (in the TensorFlow Object Detection API, while training MobileNetV2 based models)

- loss
- loss_1
- loss_2

[image: Sample of losses during training]

Comment: you didn't specify which detection model (MobileNet is not a detection model).

Comment: I'm using the ssd_mobilenet_v2 detection model

Comment: ...with the oid_v2_detection_metrics

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow Object Detection API,The loss consists of two parts, the localization loss for bounding box offset prediction and the classification loss for conditional class probabilities. Both parts are computed as the sum of squared errors. 
Two scale parameters are used to control how much we want to increase the loss from bounding box coordinate predictions and how much we want to decrease the loss of confidence score predictions for boxes without objects.

Comment: Thank you. But why does the loss chart differ that much from the loss_1/loss_2 chart?